# Wildfly 14 Microsoft SQL Server Configuration

Tags: sql-server, wildfly, datasource, mssql-jdbc, wildfly-13

I want to use MS SQL Server as a datasource in Wildfly 14, but I always get following error in the console:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "datasources"),("jdbc-driver" => "sqlserver")]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0115: Module for driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc] or one of it dependencies is missing: [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc]"
```

My configuration is as follow:

standalone.xml

```
<drivers>
    <driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
        <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
```

I also configured a module.xml in the following directory: wildfly-14.0.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\microsoft\sqlserver\main. I also put the sqljdbc42.jar in it.

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="sqljdbc42.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/> 
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/> 
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

With Wildfly 13 and before I had no problems.

Comment: I would suggest you to put your JDBC under 
 _<yourWildflyPath>\modules\com\microsoft\sqlserver\jdbc\main\sqljdbc42.jar_ (If i'm not wrong, this is a better - if not the correct - location to your JDBCs)

Comment: I already put sqljdbc42.jar in the suggested folder <yourWildflyPath>\modules\com\microsoft\sqlserver\jdbc\main\ like module.xml. Do I have to put other files in it from the microsoft download?

Comment: I don't think so. You need the .jar and the module.xml. Can you tell us if you also have <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver> this inside the <drivers> tag?

Comment: You also need to keep that "ExampleDS" datasource that comes in the standalone.xml. I always let it there, I just add my definitions. Keep that information, add yours and try to run again.

Comment: I kept the h2 driver and the "ExampleDS" datasource. This cannot be the problem.

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? Are you using Java 8? If so, can you do just one more test please? Download [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) JDBC Driver 7.0 or 6.4 for jre8 (mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar or mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar) and don't forget to change the name in your module.xml, copy the new .jar to your folder and start jboss again. I have the same configuration that you do, just tested here with these 2 .jars I mentioned and it's working.

Comment: Is there anything further up the logs? If it works in WildFly 13 it should work in WildFly 14.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your `driver` configuration in the standalone.xml is still wrong.

The following have to be the same.

In standalone.xml:

```
<driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc">
```

In module.xml:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc">
```

Location of `sqljdbc42.jar` and `module.xml`:

```
JBOSS_HOME\modules\com\microsoft\sqlserver\jdbc\main\
```

I also believe you are using the wrong xa-datasource-class, this should be:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource
```

Also have a look at [EAP7 Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuration_guide/datasource_management#example_microsoft_sqlserver_xa_datasource). It should be the same vor wildfly.
There is also a good example of how to use the CLI.

Comment: Thank you now it works . It was a combination of 2 things and wildfly 13 was less restrictive. In Wildfly 13 the declaration of the driver class in standalone.xml worked, in wildfly 14 it has to be the datasource class.

Comment: I too facing same issue i followed same above procedure but still the error not resolved, please let me know did you past the jar and module xml in the same folder mention above.

Comment: Did you follow the eap7 documentation? You really should use the cli! And yes, jdbc jar and module.xml is in the same folder, as described in the answer

Answer (score 1):

add this to module.xml inside `<dependencies>` tag

```
<module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
```

Comment: Could you clarify? What are you referring to when you say "this"?

Comment: I was having the same issue with missing dependencies while creating a datasource for mssql. Going over the logs it appeared like the sql jar is dependent upon the library that I have mentioned above. It worked for mssql14 and wildfly17. Hope this helps!